# TLP 2824 Desktop Printer How to read Printer status

Tags: c#, zpl

I am developing render utility in C#.Net for printing labels in my Kiosk application.
I have used RawPrinter class to send ZPL commands. If i print 5 labels how can i get response that printer actually print 5 or less.
I also need to read detail printer current status if its out of paper, paper low or if any problem is found.

I have saw SGD Commands ! U1 getvar "device.host_status", but not get any response.

I want to know does ZPL commands are right choice or is there any free sdk available.

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual ([ZPLII ZBI Manual](http://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf)) device.host_status is only available on the ZT200 series printer.  If you are using the Zebra Kiosk printer see this article [Get Status on Zebra Kiosk Printer](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO7383&actp=LIST_POPULAR).

I don't know if they have an SDK for the reciept printer, but if they do it will be here [Zebra Link SDK](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/zebralink.html)

Comment: I have TLP 2824 Desktop and that does not support ENQ command. When i send 3 print i want make sure does 3 are printed or less.

Comment: .Net SDK also does not seem to run with PC.